# difficulty using saxon in java code for .sch to .xsl conversion

Tags: saxon

I’m trying to use schematron validation using saxon.
Firstly,   i want to compile .sch  file into .xsl   . Later , i want to validate an .xml file with firstly produced .xsl file.

I found command line usage of saxon like below. And i used successfully them.
But i need to make these actions with java code.
I tryed some codes like below , but i did not guess how to put  sch extensined file as a parameter (edefter_yevmiye.sch) and  iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl  into the code.
I searched the internet but i did not find enough information.
Is there a sample java code for converting .sch to .xsl or could you guide me please?

**My java code**

```
    **Compiling   .sch to .xsl**

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor processor1 = new net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor(false);
             net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler xsltCompiler1 = processor1.newXsltCompiler();

             xsltCompiler1.setXsltLanguageVersion("2.0");
             xsltCompiler1.setSchemaAware(true);

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable xsltExecutable1 = xsltCompiler1.compile(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new File("File1.xsl"))));

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer xsltTransformer1 = xsltExecutable1.load();
             xsltTransformer1.setSource(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new
                      File("File2.sch"))));


   **Validation**

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor processor2 = new net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor(false);
             net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler xsltCompiler2 = processor2.newXsltCompiler();

             xsltCompiler2.setXsltLanguageVersion("2.0");
             xsltCompiler2.setSchemaAware(true);

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable xsltExecutable2 = xsltCompiler2.compile(new StreamSource(new
                      FileInputStream(new File(“File1.xslt"))));

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer xsltTransformer2 = xsltExecutable2.load();
             xsltTransformer2.setSource(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new
                      File("src.xml"))));

             net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination dest2 = new Serializer(System.out);
             xsltTransformer2.setDestination(dest2);


             xsltTransformer1.setDestination(xsltTransformer2);
             xsltTransformer1.transform();
```

**Command line usage**

***Compiling:***

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -o:output.xsl -s:some.sch iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl
```

***Validation:***

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -o:warnings.xml -s:some.xml output.xsl
```

Comment: There are lots of examples of using the s9api interface in the file called samples/S9APIExamples.java in the saxon "resources" file which you can download either from SourceForge or from the Saxonica site. You've basically got the idea right; if it's failing and you don't understand the failure, then please tell us how it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using your second transformation as the destination for the first, but that means that the output of the first transformation is used as the source document for the second, whereas you want to use it, I think, as the stylesheet for the second transformation.

The simplest way to do this is probably to set an XdmDestination for the first transformation, and then with this destination object, do destination.getXdmNode().asSource() to get the input to the compile() method for the second transformation.